# Find the value of $Z$ from the log expression of 0-1 error decomposition.

Tags: statistics, logarithms, machine-learning

I am trying to interpret the calculation of 0-1 error for classification from the [following link](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/classes/534/slides/part9.pdf) (p. 44). With the expression given below, I need help in finding out the value of $Z$.

$$\bar h = \text{argmin}_u \mathbb{E}_s[\mathrm{KL}(u, h)]$$

This turns out to be the geometric mean:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log\frac{\bar h}{1 - \bar h} &= \mathbb{E}_s\left[\log \frac{h}{1 - h}\right] \\
\bar h &= \frac{1}{Z} \exp\left(\mathbb{E}_s[\log h]\right),
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\mathbb{E}_s$ is the expected value.

Comment: I haven't read the materials carefully, but $Z$ looks like a normalization constant which makes the distribution $\bar h$ integrate to $1$, that is, $Z = \int \exp \left( \mathbb{E}_s [\log h(x)]\right) dx$. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response. Iam not sure if it satisfies the above equation.